# Как исправить ошибку NoneType object is not iterable?

Tags: python

Задача:
 Сгенерировать десять списков из случайных чисел. Вывести их и
   сумму их элементов на экран. Найти среди них один с максимальной суммой
   элементов. Указать какой он по счету, повторно вывести этот список и сумму
   его элементов. Заполнение списка и подсчет суммы его элементов оформить 
   в виде отдельных функций.

Ошибка:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\5.16.py", line 20, in <module>
    g = max(d)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Код:

```
import random
n = int(input("Введите кол-во возможных случайных:"))
b = int(input("Введите диапазон случайных значений:"))
def func_1(n,b):
    d = [[random.randrange(b) for i in range(n)] for i in range(10)]
    print("Исходные 10 списков:",d)
func_1(n,b)
def func_2(n,b):
    d = [[sum(random.randrange(b) for i in range(n))] for i in range(10)]
    print("сумма элементов в каждом из 10 списков:",d)
func_2(n,b)
d = func_2(n,b)
g = max(d)
print("Максимальная сумма элементов:",g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func_2(n,b):
    d = [[sum(random.randrange(b) for i in range(n))] for i in range(10)]
    print("сумма элементов в каждом из 10 списков:",d)
    return d      # <---
```

Comment: Спасибо,вы решили мою проблему

Comment: Да как видно из ответа S.Nick , функция должна что-то возвращать,а у вас ничего не возвращает ,т.е. NONE
max(NONE) и есть ваша ошибка